# Why is the number of elements isn't equal when transfer a list to a double vector in R

Tags: r

I am trying to `ulist` number of elements from a list to a double, but I see the number of elements are doubled from 1000 to 1000000:
here is the code:

```
e = runif(1000, min=1, max=10)
t = rpois(1000,lambda = 64.497)
mydata <- lapply(1:1000, function(i) { 
  DU = sample(x=1:3,size = 1,replace = T)
  if(DU==1){
    v=10000
    s=100     
  }
  if(DU==2){ 
    v=7500
    s=50
  }
  if(DU==3){
    v=5000
    s=10
  }    
  nt = v * (s - (t+ e))
})

t_totall = unlist(mydata)    
summary(t_totall)    
length(t_totall)    
length(mydata)
```

Comment: I don't understand. The function you pass to `lapply` will return 1,000 elements each time. And you are calling that 1,000 times. So you'll get 1,000 x 1,000 = 1,000,000 elements in the resulting vector. What exactly were you expecting to happen?

Comment: `lapply` used instead of for loop to repeat the function from 1 to 1000

Comment: And each "loop" of that lapply is returning a vector of length 1000. You're returning `nt = v * (s - (t+ e))` and since `t` and `e` are length 1000, that result is length 1000.

Comment: I see! Could you suggest a solution I want to have the value of nt for 1000 time to be saved in t_totall.

Comment: I don't understand how you want to create just 1000 values. I don't know what you expect the output to be.

Comment: I am expecting nt to have the results of its function 1000 times as a vector.

Comment: You could add a minimal reproducible example and explain more clearly what you want as output. Maybe it also helps to write things in a for loop.

Comment: The equation  `nt = v * (s - (t+ e))` needs to be repeated 1000 times with differed parameters each time. I am trying to solve it using loops but it will take significant time comparing with `lapply`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved! Instead of putting number of samples in each distribution, I putted just 1 sample in each one (runif and rpois) and in this way each iteration will take just one random variable from the certain distribution instead of getting 1000 each time.

```
mydata <- lapply(1:1000, function(i) { 
  DU = sample(x=1:3,size = 1,replace = T)
  if(DU==1){
    v=10000
    s=100     
  }
  if(DU==2){ 
    v=7500
    s=50
  }
  if(DU==3){
    v=5000
    s=10
  } 

e = runif(1, min=1, max=10)
t = rpois(1,lambda = 64.497)   
  nt = v * (s - (t+ e))
})

t_totall = unlist(mydata)    
summary(t_totall)    
length(t_totall)    
length(mydata)
```